# FirefoxDriver - selenium and XUL

Tags: xul, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a web application written in XUL and I've been trying to use FireFoxDriver to interact with the browser. I can locate an element, but when I use the sendKeys or click it doesn't trigger any event. here are my code

```
 <rows>
                        <row>
                            <spacer height="10"/>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <label class="LoginLabels" control="login" value="&LOGIN_LABEL;"/>
                            <textbox id="login" onkeypress="doKey(event)" onclick="return false;"
                                     ondblclick="return false;" persist="value" context="nocontext"/>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <spacer height="5"/>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <label class="LoginLabels" control="pass" value="&LOGIN_PASSWORD_LABEL;"/>
                            <textbox id="password" type="password" onkeypress="doKey(event)" onclick="return false;"
                                     ondblclick="return false;" context="nocontext"/>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <spacer height="5"/>
                        </row>
                    </rows>
```

and I am using Selenium's FireFoxDriver like this

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(mFirefoxProfile);
driver.get("/login.xul");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys('username');
driver.findElement(By.id("go")).click();
```

and here is the error, I get

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_23'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .WebDriverError(file:///C:/Users/POOYAN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4952327108425051793webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/resource/modules/atoms.js:8435)
    at .(file:///C:/Users/POOYAN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4952327108425051793webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/resource/modules/atoms.js:9366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, Selenium is not the tool that you want for testing these types of applications.

I would recommend using [Mozmill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Mozmill), which is a great tool for testing Addon's and is also used by the Desktop Automation team for Automating Firefox Tests. It has the ability to hook into the browser chrome and so what you want.

Comment: mozmill has been deprecated and replaced with marionette? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette