# Why can Selenium not find XUL buttons?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to use Selenium to test a [Firefox add-on](https://github.com/l0b0/insecure-links-highlighter), but it doesn't find the "Preferences" button in about:addons:

```
extensionEntry.findElement(By.className("preferences")).click();
```

results in

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .preferences

Is this the wrong way to get a reference to the button? I've tried navigating the XUL in the Inspector, and there it definitely has the right class.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium is not what you should be using to write test scripts for these type of applications.
As suggested by [AutomatedTester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108827/automatedtester), refer to his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700516/3465845

Comment: I'm having trouble following this chain of tools: [Mozmill has been superseded by Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Mozmill), but its [WebDriver page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) says it's enabled by default in Selenium 3.0 and later, coming full circle. So why would Selenium not be appropriate? I can find absolutely no documentation for how to use Marionette with the Java WebDriver though.

Comment: Here is the documentation needed, [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/). hope it helps..

Comment: Use latest version of required software packages for better compatibility

Comment: I already have the latest Geckodriver; it's part of [the Docker image I'm using](https://github.com/l0b0/insecure-links-highlighter/blob/master/selenium/Dockerfile#L60-L69).